# Run PHP v5.4 on MacOS

Tags: php, macos

is it possible to run PHP 5.4 on MacOS Big Sur? I'm trying to run an old PHP server that uses deprecated functions such as `mysql_connect`etc.

Using PHP v7.x gives error that `mysql_connect` is an undefined function.

Comment: Time to upgrade the application

Comment: That's probably the best solution, but I didn't write the code so I'm not sure how much that would require.

Comment: Otherwise your best bet might be to use a virtual machine or a container with an older Linux distribution on it where there's an old PHP package available.

Comment: If you're planning to make it accessible on internet, then I would argue that you really should refactor the application to work with newer PHP versions. 5.4 hasn't had any updates (including security fixes) in over 5 years so putting that live would be irresponsible. If the bulk of the issue is the `mysql_*`-api, then it could be a bit cumbersome but it should be pretty straight forward changing those.

Comment: I'm only planning running it locally, so I'm not too bothered about the security issue. I'll however look at refactoring, see how far I can get on that. If I can't do that, I guess I'll try a virtual machine, or even on my Win10 desktop.